# What's the size of library in unity for android?

Tags: unity, android

In unity3d what is the size of library compiled into apk.
Is that affect when i make game without any physics(2d or 3d) or when making 2d or 3d game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what's in an apk file by renaming it with a .zip extension and using the usual tools to look inside it.

That way, you can see the size of everything included in your build.